# What is the name of this kind of audio connector?

Tags: audio, media

[image]

It's the entry point of my 5+1 philips home cinema system. There are 12 points for 6 cables and every cable has 2 points to connect. I want to learn the name of the connector, so I can search if there is a converter for a regular entry point.

More detail:

My philips home cinema media player is broken after a year (board is not working), and the tech service wants 60% of the total worth of the home cinema system, which is very absurd. I just want to use 5+1 part of it and throw away the player. I will use it on my Panasonic plasma tv, which has the regular audio entry points, and HDMI entry points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called **Philips "Easy-fit"** speaker connectors. They are a proprietary feature and a p.i.t.a. ;)

Here's an article on [how to replace them](http://www.instructables.com/id/Replace-your-Easyfit-HTiB-connector/).

And here's a listing for [replacement parts on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/172219075463).

Hope that helps!